# Android : how to use mapbox with mapsforge?

Tags: java, android, dictionary, mapbox, mapsforge

I want to use `com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView` with "MapsForge" map data
how can I reach to this goal ?

I see this examples about use mapsforge with osmdroid :
https://github.com/Arman92/Mapsforge-OsmDroid-GraphHopper

but I want use mapbox with mapsforge

Answer (score 0):

Looking over MapsForge, most if not all of the features it offers can be done already in the Mapbox Android SDK with far better performance using vector tiles rather then raster. If you insist on using, i'd recommend taking a look at the work we've been doing with the Runtime Style API which allows you to add tile sources to a map. [Here's a ticket](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/issues/115) showing a bunch of the features off. Not sure whether this helps out but it will give you a starting point.

If you'd like additional help, feel free editing your question with additional information so I can test.

Comment: i want to use pre offline .map file in SD card, can mapbox use of .map file ?    i just saw "download region" in mapbox document